32 bit application stack trace
I have an old application 32bit that doesn't change. I'm developing a DLL for it.
Here is the code of my function:
void PacketHandler::CMSG_Hook(CDataStore* data)
{
   CDataStore** pointerToPacket = &data;
   printf("%p\n", pointerToPacket);
   MessageBoxA(0,"debug pause", 0, 0);
   ...
}

When I use these parameters:
/JMC /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"include" /I"../common/include" /I"../common/include/json" /I"../common/include/json/nlohmann" /I"../lua/lua-5.4.6" /I"../Microsoft DirectX SDK2010/include" /ZI /Gm- /Od /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" /D "LEGACY_FUNCTIONS_SUPPORTED" /D "WIN32" /D "INJECTED_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MT /std:c++20 /FC /EHsc /nologo /diagnostics:column

the console prints the result I expect (the argument address is outside the current stack frame)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
when I use these parameters:
/permissive- /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" /D "NDEBUG" /D "INJECTED_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MT /std:c++20 /FC /EHsc /nologo /diagnostics:column 

The function returns a pointer to the memory area of ​​the current frame:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
I want the address of the parameter which was used to call this method.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/xOlLpNiI.jpg
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/6H1w594B.jpg

This question is probably best illustrated with assembly snippets before and after "optimization"

Depending on your architecture's ABI, parameters could be passed in registers. Either get a copy of the ABI for your platform or reverse engineer it from the assembly language.

this isn't even portable across compiler's settings, one of the reasons why  "d"-suffixed .dlls exist and why you cannotand shoudn't link liberary compiled with cedrtain compiler flags set differently (in some cases you'll get warning wth new compilers). dump_stack looks like something i know from OS librart , if that's what I think, it's not compatile with C++ calls (after all, registers can be used instead stack, or passed argument wouldn't be a reference).

Have you tried Libbacktrace?

Optimized code normally doesn't waste EBP as a frame pointer.  Modern Windows has (AFAIK) stack-unwind metadata that makes it possible to backtrace even without frame pointers. At least for 64-bit code, but MSVC does omit frame pointers even in 32-bit builds, so I assume C++ exceptions are still possible without them.

GNU C void * __builtin_return_address (unsigned int level) (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005freturn_005faddress) will give you the return address for this function with 0, for the parent function with (1), etc..  I don't know what method it uses to backtrace, and it warns it can "have unpredictable effects" to call with a non-zero arg (which requires backtracing).  But if you're using GCC or Clang or other GNU C compiler, worth giving it a try.  There's also __builtin_frame_address(0) to get the address of the stack frame reliably.

void PacketHandler::CMSG_Hook(CDataStore* data)
{
CDataStore** pointerToPacket = &data;
printf("%p\n", pointerToPacket);
MessageBoxA(0,"debug pause", 0, 0);
https://sun9-71.userapi.com/impg/-05ZBjVhYuNI4DFhDtmddWZKK16JZ5cSQ2DkHA/9iRoMMsO4XI.jpg?size=1278x826&quality=96&sign=c97c04bff7985a2b6aa2d82df7809550&type=album
https://sun9-65.userapi.com/impg/ygn6uFEJDMxhGnj1ltex8vulx2CIMwvSa5moZw/-HBBDX4ucrg.jpg?size=1202x603&quality=96&sign=4c08f316d246cb95d96833260868cff0&type=album

old app uses ebp as i expect.
the problem is that i can't get the address of the argument that is pushed before the function call

Do you want the address of the copied pointer parameter or do you want the address of the parameter which was used to call this method (the one on the outer stack frame)? The parameter is a copy of the original input pointer.

you got it right, Thibe. i need the address of the parameter which was used to call this method (the one on the outer stack frame). but with different compilation flags i get different results when taking the address

Once again I suggest you edit your question with more concrete information. At a minimum we need to know what "different compilation flags" you use and what the assembly looks like with each set of flags.

The pointer Packet* packet is by definition copied by value, only the target is referenced, thus you can see packet like a local variable of your function.
When you take the reference of packet then you get the address of the parameter, not the address of the input pointer.
The compiler may decide to optimize this variable out.
If you want access to the address of the input argument, use a reference to the pointer.
Taking the address of a reference returns the address of the original parameter. You need a const reference to achieve the same usability.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void my_function1(int* packet)
{
    std::cout << &packet << "\n";
}

void my_function2(int* const& packet)
{
    std::cout << &packet << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int* pi = &i;
    std::cout << "The real address is " << &pi << "\n";
    my_function1(pi);
    my_function2(pi);
    return 0;
}


The real address is 0x7ffcd484ab50
0x7ffcd484ab38
0x7ffcd484ab50

